# Idempotency of the q-antisymmetrizer

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra, reference-request

### Background

When constructing the exterior algebra of a (finite-dimensional, complex) vector space $V$, there are two equivalent pictures.  The first is the quotient picture.  First you define the tensor algebra $T(V)$, define $\mathcal{J}$ to be the 2-sided ideal generated by elements of the form $x\otimes y + y \otimes x$, and then define the exterior algebra to be the quotient $\Lambda(V) = T(V)/\mathcal{J}$.

The other viewpoint is via embedding the exterior algebra in the tensor algebra.  This is done as follows.  There is an action $\rho$ of the symmetric group $S_n$ on $V^{\otimes n}$ for each $n$, given by 
$$\rho_\pi (v_1 \otimes \dots \otimes v_n) = v_{\pi(1)} \otimes \dots \otimes v_{\pi(n)}.$$
Then the map
$$A_n = \frac{1}{n!} \sum_{\pi \in S_n}sgn(\pi) \rho_\pi$$
is idempotent, i.e. satisfies $A_n^2 = A_n$.  If we define 
$$ A = \bigoplus_{n=0}^\infty A_n$$
on $T(V)$, then it turns out that the kernel of $A$ is equal to $\mathcal{J}$, so that $\Lambda(V) \simeq \mathrm{im}(A)$.

### Why I care

I'm trying to understand the quantum analogue of this, where $V$ is the fundamental representation/vector representation of $U_q(\mathfrak{sl}_N)$.  The problem is that there is no longer an action of the symmetric group on $V^{\otimes n}$; instead there is an action of the braid group.  Both the quotient picture and the embedding picture have analogues in the quantum setting.  In particular, denote by $\sigma$ the braiding on $V \otimes V$, and let $\sigma_i$ be the automorphism of $V^{\otimes n}$ given by $\sigma$ acting in the $i$ and $i+1$ spots.

One constructs the $q$-antisymmetrizer as follows.  Define $\tau_i$ to be the adjacent transpositions $(i, i+1)$ in $S_n$.  For a permutation $\pi$, write
$\pi= \tau_{i_1} \dots \tau_{i_k},$
where $k$ is the minimal number of adjacent transpositions needed.  Then define
$$\sigma_\pi = \sigma_{i_1} \dots \sigma_{i_k}.$$
It is a theorem that this is well-defined, i.e. that any two minimal decompositions of $\pi$ as products of adjacent transpositions can be transformed into one another using only the braid relations.  Anyway, once this is known, you can define the $q$-analogue of the antisymmetrizer map as
$$A_n =  \frac{q^{\binom{n}{2}}}{[n]!} \sum_{\pi \in S_n} sgn(\pi) q^{-\ell(\pi)} \sigma_\pi,$$
where $[n]$ is the $q$-number and $\ell(\pi)$ is the length of a minimal decomposition of $\pi$.  The significance of the $\binom{n}{2}$ is that it is the length of the longest word in $S_n$.  As far as I can tell, this was first defined by Jimbo in his 1986 paper "A $q$-analogue of $U(\mathfrak{gl}_{N+1})$, Hecke Algebra, and the Yang-Baxter Equation".  He states that $A_n^2 = A_n$, and refers to Gyoja's paper "A $q$-Analogue of Young Symmetrizer."  Gyoja's paper certainly does the trick, but I find that something is lost in the abstraction.

I've verified that $A_n^2 = A_n$ for $n = 3$, which already involves 36 terms, and it wasn't that enlightening.  The problem is that the braid generators $\sigma_i$ aren't idempotent, they instead satisfy $\sigma_i^2 = 1 + (q - q^{-1})\sigma_i$.

### The question

Does anybody know a nice way of seeing that the $q$-antisymmetrizer is idempotent, or a nice presentation of it somewhere?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This element has many expressions. It is characterised up to a scalar multiple by the property that $\sigma_iA_n=-q^{-1}A_n$ for $i=1,2,\ldots ,n-1$. It also satisfies
$A_n\sigma_i=-q^{-1}A_n$ for $i=1,2,\ldots ,n-1$. In particular it is central.

Using this property you can calculate $A_n^2$. Note that 
$\sigma_\pi A_n=(-q)^{-\ell(\pi)}= sgn(\pi)q^{-\ell(\pi)}$. So
$$A_n.\sum_\pi sgn(\pi)q^{-\ell(\pi)}\sigma_\pi=A_n.\sum_\pi q^{-2\ell(\pi)}$$

You fix the scalar factor by the condition $A_n^2=A_n$. Alternatively in the one dimensional representation $\sigma_i \mapsto -q^{-1}$ you require $A_n \mapsto 1$.

Comment: That's a nice argument.  I guess that's more or less the same as what you do for the Young symmetrizers as well, right?

Comment: Sure. Just change $-q^{-1}$ to $q$. P.S. I have fixed the signs.

Answer (score 1):

*Group Theory:  Birdtracks, Lie's, and Exceptional Groups* by Predrag Cvitanovic has a graphical way of presenting the idempotents.  His book is available online here:

http://birdtracks.eu/

Comment: See (6.16) for the diagrammatic proof.